# What XML Namespace should be used when a complex type is reference by another schema in a different namespace?

Tags: xsd

Lets say I have one schema that defines a complex type named "MyType" in the namespace "general"

Then in another schema, that complex type is used.

For instance:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/otherschema" 
          xmlns:general="http://www.example.com/genschema">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.com/genschema" schemaLocation="general.xsd" />
<xsd:element ref="general:Mytype" />
<xsd:element name="myName" type="general:MyType" />
```

Should the namespace on the XML element in the XML document that conforms to this schema use the targetNamespace of otherschema or genschema.

```
<general:MyType />
or
<targetNamespacePrefix:Mytype />
```

I am asking this question because I used Axis2 to generate the java code to interact with a web service. The Axis2 code has checks against the namespace and in the example above it would check that the namespace was the general one and throw an exception if it wasn't. Of course the web service response xml used the targetNamespace instead of the general namespace so it breaks every time. I have much more faith in the Axis2 developers than the developers of the web service, but I want to make sure I am write before filing a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of MyType in the "other" schema is correct: declare the namespace, use `import` and use the declared prefix (`general`).

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/otherschema" 
              xmlns:general="http://www.example.com/genschema">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.com/genschema" schemaLocation="general.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="myName" type="general:MyType" />
</xsd>
```

Notice that I made your `http://...` items explicit to be clear which ones are typically different in the situation you describe.

If you're asking about the schema where `MyType` is defined, use an unprefixed name for the definition in that schema:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/genschema" 
    <xsd:complexType name="MyType"> ... </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Update based on your edit:

In the XML instance document, use of `myName` would have a namespace of the "otherschema" which is targetNamespace above. Use of `MyType` would use the "genschema" namespace.

I removed the `<xsd:element ref="general:MyType"/>` which only makes sense if `MyType` is a element (not a type) and if it's inside a type definition. Suppose "otherschema" contains:

```
<xsd:complexType name="otherType>
    ...
    <xsd:element ref="general:MyElement"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

In that case, `MyElement` would still use the "genschema" namespace in the XML instance document.

Bottom line: importing items does not change their namespace. Including them, however, does change the namespace (that is, using `<xsd:include>`.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more clear from your example in your answer. I am specifically asking what the element in the XML document that conforms to this schema should use as a namespace. The general one where the complex type is defined, or the target namespace where the type is used. I believe it should be the general one.